# Is it possible to suppress fingerprinting for image assets used in emails (Rails 3.1)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

In my mailer views, I include images as follows:

```
<%= image_tag "header.png" , :alt => "" %>
```

Which results in the following HTML in the generated email

```
<img alt="" src="http://example.com/assets/header-247cf573710c22ec2c14eafefeb4c7c1.png">
```

However, in the case of images used in emails, I would prefer *NOT* to include the fingerprinting.  If I change the header image slightly, I would prefer that when a user drags up an old email, they see the new image, rather then getting an error because the old, fingerprinted URL is no longer valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails 3.1.1 both versions of assets are available, and you can use the :digest => false option to make Rails give you the plain path to the asset

`<image alt="" src="<%= asset_path 'header.png', :digest => false %>" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can set this digest for the entire project in your development or production environment config file by adding the below:

```
# Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = false
```

Comment: I tried this, but it caused all of my images and my CSS/JS not to load. Any idea how I can turn off the fingerprinting but still have everything load? Thanks!